# How To Insert a Caption in MS Word 2007?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2007, caption

How do I add a caption to an image in Word 2007?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the image
2. `References tab / Insert Caption`
3. Add **New Label** if required

[image: 1]

<sup>Sources: [1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-delete-captions-HP001228982.aspx#BM1), [2](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/quickly-add-captions-to-your-graphics-in-word-2007/)</sup>

Comment: BTW, all the question downvotes are probably due to lack of research. A simple web search would have given you the answer.